# Building executable jar with Gradle and NetBeans

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, jar, executable

I have searching to solve this problem for two days and I did not find solution. Firstly I wanted to build fat-jar, then I gave up on that it looked more complicated so I started building normal executable jar. I am building some program inside NetBeans 8.2 with Gradle plugin(http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support)

My project structure is like this:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIveP.jpg)

I am relatively new to Gradle I am using it less then one month. My ***build.gradle*** looks like this:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ..
//    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
//    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.16'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.16'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.6'


}

apply plugin: 'java'


mainClassName = "paket.Glavna"

jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": "Glavna" )
    }
}
```

Now, I cant get it working to make executable jar. I think i have traced problem that there isnt path to main class in jar but I dont know why it isnt adding it. Error i get is:

**Error: Could not find or load main class DnevniIzvestajG-1.0.jar**

jar runs with (inside Glavna class is main):
**java -cp projectname.jar paket.Glavna**

Also I have tried running 
manifest-addition
but taht also didnt add link to main class.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a package to the class with `main()` method.

```
jar {
    archiveName = 'Glavna.jar'

    manifest {attributes 'Main-Class': 'paket.Glavna'}

    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {}
}
```

Building a fat jar like this is not preferable, try the [Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/application_plugin.html)

Comment: Now I am getting this error:


* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'DnevniIzvestajG'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=org.apache.poi, name=poi, version=3.16}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: im not sure but sometimes it gets buggy with the dependencies, try a different syntax `compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.16'`

Answer (score 0):

I use below way to add all dependencies in .jar of gradle project.

**build.gradle** :-

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.main.MainClass'
        )
    }

 duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
 from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

}
```